# Why is there no implicit this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, language-design

In JavaScript, `this` must always be stated explicitly when accessing its properties. For example:

```
function Frobber(x) {
    this.x = x;
    return this;
}

Frobber.prototype.frob = function () {
    // wrong:
    return x * x;
    // right:
    return this.x * this.x;
}
```

I'm aware I can use `with(this)` (which is deprecated and generally frowned upon), but why aren't properties of `this` in scope automatically? I'm thinking there must be a reason for this design decision.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's similar in Python. The reason is quite simple: You *cannot* add this, because it clashes with the default scoping rule of searching for non-local variables in the outer scopes. It's possible in statically-typed languages, because the members of the `this` are known at compile-time.

And what if the made it a dynamic decision, such as "`x` refers to `this.x` if `this.x !== undefined` and otherwise to the variable `x`" (or any other rule for this that is decided at runtime)? That's very dangerous, as it can shadow local variables based on what `this` happens to be, i.e. breaking perfectly valid code only for certain objects. Another issue: Should `undeclaredVar = ...` add a new instance attribute? If not, that would be an ugly asymmetry between implicit and explicit `this`. If it *does* create an instance attribute, you'd lose the ability to set global and closure variable from inside functions  - not too much of a loss, many would say; but the JS designers seem to have thought otherwise, as they chose global scope as default.

Making "casual variables" shadow instance attributes would be less dangerous, but with deeply nested scopes filled with lots of names, you'd propably end up being forced to use `this.` in most cases - so less of a net win. For this, and/or propably for other reasons, the designers deemed a shortcut infeasible.

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly specify "this" because "window" is implicit instead

Code

```
function SomeFunc(x) {
    y = x;
    return this;
}
```

Is the same as

```
function SomeFunc(x) {
    window.y = x;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What "this" refers to in Javascript is *wholly* a function of how the current function has been called.

If it is called as a method (i.e. with the . operator) then 'this' will be set to the object before the dot.

If it is called as a simple function, then 'this' will be the global object (usually the window).

IIRC if you use Function.call, you can set it explicitly.

Javascript is an OO language but does *not* have classes, and does not (strictly) have methods.

Comment: Correct, but how does this relate to the question?

Comment: Because what 'this' is bound to in those examples will depend on how the functions are called.

Answer (score 2):

Each function object introduces a new namespace and populates it with its parameters, variables and inner function declarations. If all the properties of the `this` object were to be injected into this same namespace, the names would collide.

To prevent this collision, you would have to explicitly make sure that each parameter name, local variable name or function declaration name is not the same as any of the properties of the object that is referenced by `this`.

Since you can dynamically add new properties to an object, you would also have to make sure that any new property that you add, does not collide with all those parameters, variables,... in each of the objects methods.

This would be nearly impossible to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is implied to be `this.x`, how would you access variables defined as the name `x`?

```
function Frobber(x) { this.x = x; }
Frobber.prototype.frob = function() {
   var x = 'WHAT ABOUT ME';
   return x;
}
```

Comment: Works fine in other languages.  Local variables shadow object properties.

Comment: Not to mention, as @kjy112 pointed out, variables from the global scope.

Comment: @kprevas: Any dynamic languages among these? I don't know any (Python doesn't, Ruby marks instance attributes with `@`, I have no idea of Perl, Smalltalk-ish languages use something like `object slot` as far as I know).

Comment: @delnan: In Ruby local variables shadow self properties. In other cases everything executed with implicit self.

Answer (score 1):

From [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/) ([Functions -- Invocation](http://books.google.com/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&lpg=PA27&ots=HHunr6x3lF&dq=crockford%20javascript%20invocation&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

> There are four patterns of invocation in JavaScript: the method invocation pattern, the function invocation pattern, the constructor invocation pattern, and the apply invocation pattern.

Basically, each of these "patterns" determine how the `this` reference is defined. If a function is defined as a method of an object, `this` will refer to the parent object. If the function is not a property of an object, `this` refers to the global object. If the function is invoked with the `new` keyword (i.e. as a constructor) then `this` refers to the newly created object. And finally, if you use the function's [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) method the reference of `this` is bound to whatever object you specify.

Comment: How does it not answer the question? The reference is not defined until you invoke the function, and it depends on how you invoke the function as to how it is defined. Therefore, you can't know what `this` is until the function is invoked.