# Phaser - For loop throwing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, phaser-framework

I am trying to build a simple game using Phaser.js and I've come across an issue when looping through an array.

```
var EnemyGroup = function(enemies) {
    game.add.group();
    this.enemies = enemies;
    this.addEnemies(this.enemies);
    //return this;
};

EnemyGroup.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Group.prototype);
EnemyGroup.prototype.constructor = EnemyGroup;

EnemyGroup.prototype.addEnemies = function(enemies) {
    console.log(enemies.length);
    for (var i=0;i<enemies.length;i++) {
        console.log(i);
        this.add(enemies[i]);
    }
    console.log('done');
};
```

Above, when I create an instance of an `EnemyGroup`, I call the function `this.addEnemies`. Which, after it loops through the array, throws the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

To understand why, I had the console log the count of the array and log the index it is currently on as it loops. There is only 1 object in the array.

The output is:

`1` <-the array count (correct)

`0` <-the index it is on (also correct as there is only one object in the array)

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` <-the error

I check to see if the error is being caused outside of the for loop by having the console log `Done`... but it does not log this, so I know it's messing up somewhere in the `for loop`.

Comment: If you add a `console.log` _after_ `this.add(enemies[i]);`, does it get executed?

Comment: no, which is a lead that I hadn't found before. this implies that the `enemy` object is not being added for some reason

Comment: Yes, the error is thrown in the `this.add()` call. I encourage you to learn about JavaScript debugging, it would make it easier for you than inserting a ton of `console.log` everywhere.

Comment: Can you change your tag to phaser-framework?

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you forgot to add `this` when referencing `enemies` on `addEnemies()`

```
var EnemyGroup = function(enemies) {
    game.add.group();
    this.enemies = enemies;
    this.addEnemies(this.enemies);
    //return this;
};

EnemyGroup.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Group.prototype);
EnemyGroup.prototype.constructor = EnemyGroup;

EnemyGroup.prototype.addEnemies = function(enemies) {
    console.log(this.enemies.length);
    for (var i=0;i<this.enemies.length;i++) {
        console.log(i);
        this.add(this.enemies[i]);
    }
    console.log('done');
};
```

Related problem: [Why is there no implicit this in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875950/why-is-there-no-implicit-this-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var EnemyGroup = function(game) {
    Phaser.Group.call(this, game);
};

EnemyGroup.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Group.prototype);
EnemyGroup.prototype.constructor = EnemyGroup;

EnemyGroup.prototype.addEnemies = function(enemies) {
    for (var i=0;i<enemies.length;i++) {
        if (enemies[i]) {
            this.add(enemies[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Then in main.js:

```
enemyGroup = new EnemyGroup(game);
enemyGroup.addEnemies(pikas);
```